# How to get the XPath of an element in HTML in java?

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath, xhtml

I want to achieve a simple task, but I'm struggling to find an easy solution for that: I have the HTML of a webpage in a String (or File) and I'd like to generate the XPath of a given element.
(For example I'd like to retrieve the XPath for an `<a>` element)

I tried different solutions but I'm constantly encountering problems in parsing the html correctly. Is there a functioning html cleaner for java like this one?
https://www.htmlwasher.com/
This is the ONLY functioning cleaner I've find out for now, but it is an online tool. With this I can easily parse the HTML and get to the XPath.

I'm currently using jOOX (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX) this way to generate the XPath:

```
Document document = $(html).document();
System.out.println($(document).find("a").xpath());
```

If the HTML is cleaned with the online tool I provided, I can generate the right XPath.
I like the way I could interact with jOOX if only I could correctly and programmatically parse the html. Do you know a good way to parse the HTML?
I already tried:

- JSoup
- Tagsoup
- HtmlCleaner

The testing website page is http://www.ansa.it.

**EDIT**:
The parsing was failing on some common HTML parsing problems like unclosed tags ( `</img>` for example), escaping, etc.

I managed to parse "correctly" the html this way:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed()));
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml)
                        .syntax(Syntax.xml)
                        .charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Fact is that tags like `<a href="cinema.shtml">Cinema</a>` became `<a>Cinema</a>` so I'm not able to select them using their attributes, like href. How can I solve this new problem?

I noticed that some links still have their href and they are the ones which point to other websites like Facebook or Twitter. Could this be related?

Comment: What in particular is it failing on when uncleaned?

Comment: I edited the question! @aglassman By the way i was failing on some unclosed tags, <!DOCTYPE> not allowed and things like those. I managed to get it work cleaning the html but some weird things happens: many of the <a> tags lost their href attribute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**:

I managed to get all things to work this way:

```
String html = getTheHTMLSomeWay();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.clean(html, "http://base.uri", Whitelist.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks(true)));
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml).syntax(Syntax.xml).charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

org.w3c.dom.Document document = $(doc.html()).document();

System.out.println($(document).find("a[href='/your/relative/url']"));
```

With **Jsoup** i can clean the HTML against all that boring unclosed tags, not allowed tags etc. Then i can escape all the unescaped characters (according to **xhtml**) and set the syntax to **xml**.

That can give you a clean html code, usable with **jOOX** library.